# Can I visit France from Germany if I have a 6 months National Visa valid for Deutschland?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, france, indian-citizens

I've got an employment visa for 6 months to Germany. I'd like to visit Paris, France(Family) during the holidays. Will I be allowed to? My visa states that it is valid for Deutschland. Do I need an additional visa to enter France?
I'm an Indian National.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A national visa (type D) allows you to visit other Schengen countries for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.  See for example [Long-stay visa holders to have greater freedom to move around the EU](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=IM-PRESS&reference=20100308IPR70123&format=XML&language=EN).

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I'm just wondering, if its 90 days, how is that tracked? Do I have to submit my passport when I enter France to start the count?

Comment: @Sheldor it's not routinely tracked.  It seems that the time restriction is only likely to become an issue if someone comes to the attention of the immigration authorities or other police officers for some reason.